# New files created by other users not showing in TFS using codeplex

Tags: codeplex

I created a ASP.Net project in codeplex, and shared it with my other team mates. We are using TFS in VS 2010 as source control. The problem is if any user creates a new file in his workspace and "checks in" using TFS. The other users are not able to see this new file in their workspaces (even after doing "get latest version"). 
Is this a bug or am I missing anything here.

Note: The new file checked in is visible in the codeplex website under source code tab of the project.

Comment: By item, do you mean Changeset? Have you tried Get Specific Version and choosing the "Override mine" option?

Comment: Item is any file in the project. .aspx, .cs , .xml . New files added to the project by other users are not visible. "Get specific version" shows only the files in your workspace, while I am not able to see these files at all.

Comment: Can you see the files in the Source Control section of Visual Studio?

Comment: yes i see them. I am now able to add them by doing "get latest version" in source control and then add existing item in the solution explorer. But why should i do all this, can't i just say get latest version after opening the project and this should take care of everything, right?

Comment: Are the other users checking in the csproj files? Do the csproj files have the TFS Binding's (File, Source Control, Bindings) setup correctly?

Comment: I did not ask them that. And the setup that you are talking about, Is there any document for that.

Comment: There's not much to it: http://codeplex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Updating%20Your%20TFS%20Source%20Control%20Bindings&referringTitle=Using%20TFS%20and%20Team%20Explorer%20with%20CodePlex

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should see these new files in the Source Control. To download these changes, your workspace should map folders with changed files. If you add some files into your project, you should also check-in your project file changes.

Or if you add some files into your existing TFS project and you forget to add new files into the TFS, your new files will be missing in Source Control.